# Physics.CheckSphere() appears not to work in Unity

Tags: unity

My scene is simple, I have a single `GameObject` with the following script attached:

```
usings ...

public class GalaxyManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    public int numberOfStars = 300;
    public int maximumRadius = 100;

    public float minDistBetweenStars = 2f;

    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++)
        {
            float distance = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, maximumRadius);
            float angle = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 2 * Mathf.PI);

            Vector3 cartPosition = new Vector3(distance * Mathf.Cos(angle), 0, distance * Mathf.Sin(angle));

            if (!Physics.CheckSphere(cartPosition, minDistBetweenStars))
            {
                GameObject star = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
                star.transform.position = cartPosition;
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

What this is supposed to do is generate 300 "stars" within the `maximumRadius` of 100 that are separated by at least `minDistBetweenStars`.

I haven't been able to figure out what's actually happening -- sometimes the check finds a collider and sometimes it doesn't.  It's almost as if the `CheckSphere()` check is happening before the stars get placed via the `star.transform.position = cartPosition`.

I'm very new to Unity and appreciate the help.  Anyone have any idea what's going on?

*edit:

Some more information, I've tried the script in both 2020.1.12f1 and 2019.4.14f1 to no avail.

I'm also aware that this will lead to an infinite loop if it can't find a placement.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/what-is-wrong-with-my-physics-checkbox-use.847672/) thread? Unsure if it is still valid, but it says that assignments to `star.transform.position` might not be propagated to the physics colliders immediately.

Comment: That's an interesting thread, that's the behavior that I think I see, but the Unity guy later in the thread says it shouldn't happen.  I am not explicitly adding Collider's to the object when they're created, so perhaps they're being created without them and then they're added later after the physics check?

Comment: From what I gathered from the thread, the behaviour might be that the colliders are instantiated at the world origin, and only later moved to where you assign the transform position to be.

Comment: Yes, now that would make sense with some of the odd behavior I've seen.  Ok, so that being the case, the quick fix is to set ```Physics.autoSyncTransforms = true;``` at the beginning of the ```Start()``` method and back to false at the end.  The alternative is to create a prefab and Instantiate it at the appropriate transform location.